# How to SUM with missing numbers substituted with most recent records

Tags: sql, vertica

Suppose the game has 5 levels, and for each level players can gain a score of 1, 2 and 3. Player X has the following data:

```
Level | Attempt | Score
1     | 1       | 2  
1     | 2       | 3
2     | 1       | 3
3     | 1       | 3
4     | 1       | 1
4     | 2       | 3
5     | 1       | 2
5     | 2       | 2
5     | 3       | 3
```

Now that I want to `SUM` the scores `GROUP BY` attempt, but in a special way:

Attempt 1: Simply 2 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 3 = 12

Attempt 2: Now that Level 2 and 3 do not have Attempt 2, but I still want to use their most recent score to add up: 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2 = 14

Attempt 3: Again I want to add up all levels with their most recent score (if there is no attempt 3), so I get 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 15

How can I do it with SQL? **Please note that there is no limitation on the number of attempts**, so a player may actually attempt a level 100 times and I have to provide 100 sums.

Comment: "Most recent score".  What does that mean?  I see no timing information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff scores from the most recent attempt should be more appropriate.

Comment: Your explanation does not seem to match the sample data. For attempt 3, you only have one row with level 5, and score of 3. Can you explan or , if applicable, correct?

Comment: @marcothesane sure, lemme explain. For all attempts, I want each level to "participate", even if it does not have such attempt. For example, Level 5 does have an Attempt 3 with a Score of 3, however the other levels do not have a third attempt, but I'll take the scores of most recent attempt. So Level 1 has score 3 from Attempt 2, and Level 2 has score 3 from Attempt 1 and so on. That's where 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 comes from. I understand it's bit weird, but I can't change either the requirement or the data.

Comment: @marcothesame so essentially just imagine doing this in Excel with attempts in columns and scores in rows (3 rows * 5 columns). In first row you have scores 2, 3, 3, 1, 2 for Level 1 ~ 5, and in second row and third row you need to pull down the data if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Then, it could be something like this:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
input(level,attempt,score) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 4,2,3
UNION ALL SELECT 5,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,2
UNION ALL SELECT 5,3,3
)
-- your input ends here
, -- replace comma with WITH in real query ..
-- creating a table with 5 rows per each of the 3 attempts
frame (level,attempt) AS (
  SELECT
     i.level
   , a.attempt
   FROM input i
   CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT
       attempt
     FROM input
    ) a
   WHERE i.attempt=1
)
-- SELECT * FROM frame; -- un-comment this line to test the frame table
,
gapfilled AS (
-- Query before GROUPing: left join the frame table with the input table
-- and fill the resulting NULLs using the LAST_VALUE ( ... IGNORE NULLS) 
-- OLAP function. If you can take a previous one, pick it, if not , pick
-- a following one. 
-- Vertica has named OLAP windows, which we use here - one forward, one backward
  SELECT
    frame.level
  , NVL(
      LAST_VALUE(input.attempt IGNORE NULLS) OVER(fwd)
    , LAST_VALUE(input.attempt IGNORE NULLS) OVER(bwd)
    )  AS attempt
  , NVL(
      LAST_VALUE(input.score   IGNORE NULLS) OVER(fwd) 
    , LAST_VALUE(input.score   IGNORE NULLS) OVER(bwd)
    )  AS score
  FROM frame LEFT JOIN input USING(level,attempt)
  WINDOW fwd AS (PARTITION BY frame.attempt ORDER BY frame.level)
  ,      bwd AS (PARTITION BY frame.attempt ORDER BY frame.level DESC)
)
-- SELECT * FROM gapfilled ORDER BY 2,1; -- UN-comment to test gapfilled table
SELECT
  attempt
, SUM(score) AS score_sum
FROM gapfilled
GROUP BY
  attempt;
-- out  attempt | score_sum 
-- out ---------+-----------
-- out        1 |        11
-- out        2 |        14
-- out        3 |        15
```